# how to describe Java nest List in protobuf file?

Tags: java, protocol-buffers, protobuf-java

I have a Java Class,include a nest List field like :

```
private List<List<List<Integer>>> data;
```

but how to describe it in protobuf file?
I try it like this ,but it can not work

```
repeated repeated repeated double data = 1;
```

==============updated=====================

I tried İlker Korkut's answer, but when I want to convert a json to protobuf, it failed. my json as below:

```
{"data":[[[139,35],[138,34]]]}
```

and my protobuf file as below:

```
syntax = "proto3";
option java_package = "com.y.probuf";

message A {
    message B{
        message C {
            repeated int32 score = 1;
        }
        repeated C item = 1;
    }
    repeated B data = 1;
}
```

use java code to convert json to protobuf :

```
User.A.Builder builder = User.A.newBuilder();
JsonFormat.parser().merge(s,builder);
User.A a = builder.build();
System.out.println(a.toString());
```

it throws exception "Expect message object but got: [[139,35],[138,34]]"

maven file as below:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.protobuf</groupId>
    <artifactId>protobuf-java</artifactId>
    <version>3.6.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.protobuf</groupId>
    <artifactId>protobuf-java-util</artifactId>
    <version>3.6.1</version>
</dependency>
```

please help me !

Answer (score 0):

According to protobuf docs; you have to create nested message types to hold your data in a nested list when needed.

There is an example which I prepared;

```
syntax = "proto3";
package protobuf;

option java_package = "mypackage";
option java_outer_classname = "MyObject";

message A {
    message B {
        message C {
            repeated string name = 1;
        }
        repeated C c = 1;
    }
    repeated B b = 1;
}
```

Of course you can define message types outer and pass as a property in your parent message.

Comment: @wang8118 my answer was just an example , can you adjust nesting size according to your requirements ?